# Grouping the nested loop elements based on the first iteration variable in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have 2 lists one for the sentence one for the keywords. The idea is to check if the sentence have the keywords. and put them in a list for each sentence in order.

I am sorry if this is already duplicated here in advance.

```
List <String> sentence= new ArrayList <>();
sentence.add("this is a good dog");
sentence.add("cats drink milk");
sentence.add("Animals are beautiful creatures");

List <String> keyword= new ArrayList <>();
keyword.add("dog");
keyword.add("cats");
keyword.add("beautiful");
keyword.add("good");
keyword.add("are");
keyword.add("this");
keyword.add("milk");
```

My idea was to create 2 nested loops for each list:

```
for (int b = 0; b < sentence.size(); b++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < keyword.size(); c++) {
        if (sentence.get(b).contains(keyword.get(c))) {
            System.out.println(keyword.get(c));
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
dog
good
this
cats
milk
beautiful
are
```

The desired output would be:

```
[this,good,dog]
[cats,milk]
[are,beautiful]
```

So it is like getting all the existing keywords, in the order of the sentence,not related to keywords order.

and then group the existing keywords for each sentence, as in the order of existence.

Hope it is clear. Would really appreciate any ideas. doesnt have to follow the same method.

Comment: yeah thanks for the suggestion, I change it to old school one from time to time. I will look for the Map in this case. makes sense to me, but if you could provide an example, also would be nice.

Comment: use `java.util.ArrayList.contains(Object)` and get rid of the nested loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over your `sentence` list. For each sentence iterate over your `keyword` list. Add each found keyword found in a tempList, sort the tempList by the index of keyword in sentence and finally add each tempList to a list of lists. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List <String> sentence= new ArrayList <>();
    sentence.add("this is a good dog");
    sentence.add("cats drink milk");
    sentence.add("Animals are beautiful creatures");

    List <String> keyword= new ArrayList <>();
    keyword.add("dog");
    keyword.add("cats");
    keyword.add("beautiful");
    keyword.add("good");
    keyword.add("are");
    keyword.add("this");
    keyword.add("milk");

    List<List<String>> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for(String sen: sentence){
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String key: keyword){            
            if(sen.contains(key)){
                tempList.add(key);
            }
        }
        tempList.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                   return sen.indexOf(o1) -  sen.indexOf(o2) ;
                }
        });
        result.add(tempList);
    }
    for(List<String> r : result){
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a slight modification in your looping

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
    String[] matchArray = new String[sentence.get(i).split(" ").length];
    for (int j = 0; j < keyword.size(); j++) {
        if (sentence.get(i).contains(keyword.get(j))) {
            matchArray[Arrays.asList(sentence.get(i).split(" ")).indexOf(keyword.get(j))] = keyword.get(j);
        }
    }
    List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String match: matchArray) {
        if(match != null) {
            matchList.add(match);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(matchList);
}
```

For every sentence create an `array` with size same as the sentence (just to ensure size). Now when matches are found get the index of the match from sentence and add element to that particular index of the `array`. So at the end of keyword iteration you will have all matches in array with `null` values if some words are not matching.

Now declare a new `List` of String into which add the elements from array which are not null. At last print the list.

Comment: You need to sort the matches in the order of their apperance in the sentence. While your approach will print `[dog,good,this]` for the first sentence the OP wanted it to be `[this,good,dog]`.

Comment: This is a very smilar and good solution, but except the order should be as it is in the sentence, not by the list of keywords.

Comment: @Sojimanatsu the code is maintained to keep the order of sentence

Answer (score 1):

I think Map would be a good choice here. Just make sentences keys for the map and keywords as value. Following is the code for the same.

```
Map <String, ArrayList<String>> sentences= new HashMap<>();
sentences.put("this is a good dog", new ArrayList<>());
sentences.put("cats drink milk", new ArrayList<>());
sentences.put("Animals are beautiful creatures", new ArrayList<>());

List <String> keyword= new ArrayList <>();
keyword.add("dog");
keyword.add("cats");
keyword.add("beautiful");
keyword.add("good");
keyword.add("are");
keyword.add("this");
keyword.add("milk");

keyword.forEach(word -> sentences.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(map -> map.getKey().contains(word)).
        forEach(map -> sentences.computeIfAbsent(map.getKey(), key->new ArrayList<>()).add(word)));

sentences.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(value));
```

Comment: requires too much modification. But i like the idea anyways. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

this should do it, printing exactly in the format you requested :

```
for (int b = 0; b < sentence.size(); b++) {
     String arr[] = sentence.get(b).split("\\s+");
     List result = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int c = 0; c < arr.length; c++ ) {             
         if (keyword.contains(arr[c])) 
             result.add(arr[c]);        
     }
     System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    for (String sen: sentence) {
        System.out.print("[");
        boolean first = true;
        for (String word: sen.split("[\\s\\p{Punct}]")) {
            if (keyword.contains(word)) {
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.print(",");
                }
                System.out.print(word);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
```

Comment: it's implied from the desired output that results are in a List. So I think it would be better to have the results printed from a List instead of printing explictily ',' and '[]'

Comment: @funkyjelly that's what you did in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following :

```
for(String currentSentence : sentence) {
    List<String> keywordsInSentence = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word : currentSentence.split("\\s+")) {
        if (keyword.contains(word)) {
            keywordsInSentence.add(word);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(keywordsInSentence);
}
```

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/EkjAp3).

(and I'd rename `sentence` into `sentences` or `sentenceList` and similarly for `keyword`, otherwise it's just confusing)

If you need to do anything more to the keywords than immediately displaying them, you could insert the `keywordsInSentence` lists into a `Map<String, List<String>>` you would value by replacing the `System.out.println` by `map.put(currentSentence, keywordsInSentence)`.