# Why we can't add element into a List to nth index before adding element to (n-1)th index even if initial capacity is provided

Tags: java, arrays, list, indexoutofboundsexception

Suppose I declare an array of `int` with size 10, I can add an element to its 4th index, I can run the code without any exception.

```
int[] ar = new int[10];
ar[4] = 8;      
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar)); //works fine
```

That's because when I say size as 10, that much memory space will be allocated for that array with initial value of its type kept in each index.

But the case is not same in `List`. Say I declare a list with an initial capacity of 10 and I try to add an element to its 4th index it gives

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
list.add(4, 8); //exception
```

Of course the size of the list will return `0` even if initial capacity is given. Why is it not like Array, I think no memory is allocated for 10 elements for the list?

I was guessing that is there any way to fill List with default values once a capacity is given just like an array.

Comment: The *capacity* doesn't change the logical *size* of the list... and that's what `add` checks. Allocating a specific capacity is effectively an optimization which doesn't affect whether other operations work or not.

Comment: The list has *capacity* for 10 elements, but it does not, at the time of the `add()`, have actual elements 0 - 7.  The index 8 is therefore not meaningful with respect to that list, at that time.

Comment: The initial capacity is and remains 10, but ArrayList internally stores what the current list size is (which is 0) and then refuses to place something at the 4th place.

Comment: that behavior is described in the javadoc, please refer to it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By now it should be clear that the initial capacity on the constructor is just a bit of memory management for the initial internal array. Without any semantical meaning.

When the actual `size()` overflows the array, the array is reallocated.

There is no such thing as a bulk allocation with initial elements. However there is:

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.nCopies(10, Integer.valueOf(0));
```

And the new `Stream` offers ways to dynamically generate lists.

You could do:

```
public <T> void add(List<T> list, int i, T obj) {
    while (list.size() < i) {
        list.add(null);
    }
    list.add(i, obj);
}
```

But it is immediately evident, that you'll introduce **null**s which is unsafe and ugly,
requiring null checks.

Comment: Nice idea! Good addendum to that other answer ;-)

Answer (score 8):

This is what the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-) for ArrayList says about `add(int index, E element)`:

> throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

The **size** is the number of elements currently stored, not the current *capacity*.

The fact that your car has the "capacity" to drive with 100 mph, that doesn't mean that you can magically get from 0 to 90 mph within 1 second ;-)

In other words: the answer is that size and capacity aren't the same. Capacity merely means: "that is the size this list can grow to before the underlying array needs to grow".

Comment: nice example :-)

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran There is always a bad car example just round the corner ;-)

Comment: I was hoping that the things would go the way I thought, but it didn't and that's why I had to take a round turn https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804183/7218656

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran There is always a chance to learn something new here, each day.

Comment: @GhostCat R you a genius or what? - Programming Newb :D

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in their answers, in `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10)`, the `10` specifies the initial **capacity**.

Specifying the initial capacity is only an **optional** thing. You exercise that option only when you use the particular constructor that accepts an initial capacity as an argument. When you use other constructors, you don't have control over the initial capacity.

You specify `n` as the initial capacity if you want the first `n` additions to the list to be as efficient as possible -- otherwise, there is a possibility that the addition of each individual item to the list results in some costly internal re-sizing and re-copying into the re-sized internal area.

The above does not answer the question of why you are not allowed to add an item at position 8, when there is no item at position 7.

As some have answered, that's because [the API doc says so](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-).

That's one way to answer it. But why does the API doc say so? Why are things designed so?

Things are designed so, because:

1. Adding an item at position 8, when there is no item at position 7, results in a gap (before position 8).
2. As a programmer, you will then have to keep track of what an item's position is, **among all possible positions (the full capacity)**. Currently, as a programmer, you only keep track of what the item's position is, **among all added items**. Now, wouldn't that be a **programming nightmare**?